# I am looking for any easy excel dynamic formula to find the amount for each Week per person as per attached list

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I have below data and I need Week wise and Name wise Amount through a dynamic formula. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$14:$F$16=$B2)*--($A$13:$F$13=$A2)*(IF(ISNUMBER($B$14:$G$16),$B$14:$G$16,0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must reorganize your data into 3 columns week, name, and amount, and then you can use the pivot table to calculate the amount for each week per person

Comment: I wish I could. But I can't. That's not the data I maintain.